# Restful model ownership validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, authorization

I know there are role based authorization gems/plugins for rails to determine if a user can do things based on which role their in.  However, is there a best-practice approach to hiding actions from users based on ownership?  ie: the show/edit/destroy methods for a user should only be available if they're being performed on the currently logged in user id.  Hopefully that makes sense, but I've written some methods to protect against non-owners accessing methods and its become a bit bloated and ugly.

Comment: Could you share some code with us to comment on?

Comment: To avoid posting tons of crappy code, I basically wrote a method in each controller (will refactor to move to a single method in app controller) that essentially was http://pastie.org/1428824

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [cancan's](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) implementation.

Comment: I like this approach... Define "abilities" in a single location and then run if's on can? and authorize!... Exactly what I was looking for.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend on restful_authentication( https://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication ). quick tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/67-restful-authentication

Comment: I had looked at restful_authentication briefly based on that exact screencast, but decided to go with Authlogic for my authorization needs.

Comment: Bradley, I cam to the same conclusion. I use Authlogic and Cancan to do authentication and authorization.